# Question about the implicit function

Tags: calculus

Consider the [implicit function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zub8c.png) $$x\ln x = \ln\cot^{-1}(y).$$ Compute $y'(x).$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, it isn't all that implicit...

Comment: I derived the y = xInx to 1 + Inx but i'm not sure what to do about the Incot^-1(y)

Comment: make a function as explict form.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x\ln x = \ln\cot^{-1}(y),\iff{\ln\cot^{-1}(y)=x\ln x},\iff{arcctg\left({y}\right)={e}^{x\cdot{ln\left(x\right)}}},\iff
$$
$$
\iff{ctg}\left(arcctg\left({y}\right)\right)={ctg}\left({e}^{x\cdot{ln\left(x\right)}}\right),\iff{y}={ctg}\left({e}^{x\cdot{ln\left(x\right)}}\right),\implies
$$
$$
\implies{y^{'}\left(x\right)}=-\frac{1}{\sin^{2}{\left({e}^{x\cdot{ln\left(x\right)}}\right)}}\cdot{\left(ln(x)+1\right)}\cdot{e}^{x\cdot{ln\left(x\right)}}.
$$

$\bbox[lightgreen]{The\quad{main}\quad{feature}\quad{is:}}$

The formula $ctg(arcctg(x))=x$ can be used if $0\lt{x}\lt\pi$.

Good luck!

Comment: @student1847, If my answer helped you, mark this theme as **solved**.

Comment: Please respect [the guidelines for enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Thank you.